# google maps api terms

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to use google maps API and have a question:
google says (http://www.google.com.ua/intl/en/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html) that if I use google maps I have restrictions for those services:
1) geocoding service
2) directions service
3) distance matrix service
4) eleveation service
but what about simple API? I mean are there any restrictions if I use lets say only function that adds marker to a map and function that shows the place on the map where particular point is located? 
Thanks. Sorry for noob question but I've read terms and conditions few times and still not sure about the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restrictions i know about:

- Not more than eight waypoints per route
- Limited request-rates. It will be slow enough if you request one direction in one second.
- No implementation on serverside. You will have to implement the Google API on clientside.

From Google:

```
2,500 directions requests per day.
When the mode of transportation is driving, walking, or cycling, each directions search counts as a single request.
Searching for transit directions counts as 4 requests.
Individual requests for driving, walking, or cycling directions may contain up to 8 intermediate waypoints in the request. Waypoints can not be specified for transit requests.
```

Concerning simple API:

There are no restrictions. :)

Comment: Thanks. But I didnt mean directions service at all. I mean very simple functions: add marker, show the place where the point contains. That's all. No routes, no geocoding, no distances, no eleveations :)

Comment: What about if I want to show some boundary? I mean if I have some bunch of points that represent boundary (for example, state boundary, or city, or smth) and want to show all those points on the map? That's ok - no restrictions?

Comment: Markers are not mentioned, so that would be okay.